# Should I say "the trap that lay ahead" or "the trap that lie(s) ahead"?

Tags: word-usage, tenses, future-in-past, lie-lay-lain-laid

Which is correct?

1. My vision widened that day, and I began to see the trap that **lay ahead** for most people.
2. My vision widened that day, and I began to see the trap that **lie ahead** for most people.

Or maybe both are incorrect and some future tense of *lie* must be used?

I am confused because someone is talking about his past and others’ future that may or may not have faced the trap by the present. The trap the author talks about is kind of a fact of life.

Comment: To improve my answer, in your examples, are you speaking in the past tense or in the present tense?

Comment: It is a statement from a book.He is talking about 'that day'.

Comment: *It is a statement from a book.* Which book? In the book there is only one of the examples - which is it? Also have a look at subject-verb agreement.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you change 'lie' to 'lies' in the second variant, both sentences would be correct, but have a slightly different emphasis.

You need to change 'lie' to 'lies' because 'the trap' is third person singular and requires an 's' in present indicative. (If you google: "Lie verb table" you will get lots of hits on the grammatic form. I'm linking to one [here](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-lie.html)).

In the first, the past tense is used consistently. The account is all in the past:
**began** to see the trap that **lay** ahead. (From the perspective of the writer both events are in the past. But at the point that he began to see the trap, the trap was in the future; thus 'ahead')

In the second the indication is that at that (past) time he **began** to see a trap that *still* or *generally* **lies** ahead for most people.

---

I realise from your comment that you didn't quite understand, so I'll see if I can make it clearer. Imagine I'm writing now as an adult about an event from childhood. I was learning to swim.

> I had had three swimming lessons and decided I could swim, but I did
>   not know about **the trap that lay ahead**. I swam out into the ocean as
>   far as I possibly could, but there were strong undercurrents and I
>   could not swim back. In the end I was rescued by a lifeguard.

(In the example, the trap does not lie ahead from my present day perspective. But it lay ahead before I swam out into the ocean -- thus 'lay'.)

I'm still an adult and writing now about something else from childhood.

> I was 4 years old and assumed I would live forever. I did not know
>   then about **the trap** (death) **that lies ahead** for all of us
>   mortal creatures.

(This 'trap' lies ahead from my present day perpective.)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Good and to the point answer but are you sure ?, I am asking because you wrote 'imo'.Can you confirm from a resource ?.Also in the book the 1st statement was given(not second) and  the trap was kind of a fact of life and is general ,so I thought the second statement should be used that's why the question .Also what is wrong with lie ? What would the sentence mean if lie is used instead of lies ?. Sorry for the late reply I'm new here and forgot that I had an account.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure! I wrote 'imo', because the other commenter had a different opinion. The resource in this case was my own knowledge of English as a native speaker. I don't have time at this moment, but if noone else does, I'll search out some verb tables and references later. Grammatically you cannot use 'lie' in the second sentence; 'it lies' is the present form, third person indicative.

Comment: @Learner47 In the meantime I've put some more info into the answer which may help.

Answer (score 0):

*Lay* can either be used as a transitive verb (one that requires a direct object) or as the past tense of *lie*. If you’re speaking in the **present tense** in your example, then you should use *lies ahead,* since there is no direct object. And make sure to say “***lies*** ahead,” as “trap” is singular, not plural.

Then again, if you are speaking in the **past tense**, then you would say that the trap “lay ahead,” even though it sounds like a present usage—the past tense for the transitive verb *lay* would be *laid*.

Comment: Which sentence do you prefer ?     The author talks about his past but others future .

Comment: @Learner47 It’s not about what I prefer. It’s about what is grammatically correct.

Comment: @Learner47 If you are talking in the past tense in your example, then you should use the singular intransitive past verb “lays.”

Comment: Sorry, but this is very confusing. Are you advocating the usage of the past tense of the verb _lie_ with an "s"  (lays)? In other words forming a past tense inflection? From your answer : "if you are speaking in the past tense, then you would say that the trap *“lays ahead,*” "

Comment: The OP wanted to know what is correct. As there is no direct object in the OP’s example, the OP must use the intransitive verb “lies.” If the OP is speaking in the past tense, the OP must use the past tense of “lies”, which is “lay.”

Comment: Nathan is absolutely right.

Comment: @tautophile. I thought Cascabel was absolutely right :-)
I mean in the sense that the description 'the intransitive past verb lay' is confusing (not wrong), since the base form of this verb is 'lie' with 'lay' being the past form. The other verb, the transitive one, is 'lay' with the past form being 'laid', but I'm not sure if this is helpful in the context of the question, since 'lie' is the verb being used. I'm also curious to know why my own answer was downvoted. I accept it, of course... But would like to know the rationale.

Comment: @SConroy You can’t say both sentences are correct unless you know the author’s intent.

Comment: Grammatically both sentences would actually be correct if an 's' was added to 'lie', which is what I wrote in my answer, but they have different meanings. But that could still be why it was downvoted, so thanks for your answer.

Comment: @SConroy Both sentences are correct only if, in the first example, the author is speaking in the past tense. If not, then the author is using a transitive verb intransitively, and that is ungrammatical.

Comment: As I see it, in both cases he is using the intransitive verb 'lie', in the first example in the past simple form and in the second in the present form (referring to the future). I don't think he is using the transitive verb 'lay' at all. And this site is way too addictive. I'm getting back to work...